# JavaFX: bind LocalDateProperty to StringProperty with custom Formatter

Tags: java, date, binding, javafx

I want to bind a `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>` to a `TextField` and format the date according to the current locale or a custom Formatter.

At the moment I use

```
myTextfield.textProperty().bind(myObject.myDateProperty().asString());
```

this produces a string in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD). How to get e.g. DD.MM.YYYY?

Comment: You have to use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @EthylCasin SimpleDateFormat is not for the new Date & Time API introduced in Java SE 8.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, found a simple solution (using `Bindings.createStringBinding`):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
myTextfield.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
    dtf.format(myObject.myDateProperty().get()), myObject.myDateProperty())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a different approach: use a [DatePicker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) instead of a TextField directly.

You then can use the [converter property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#converterProperty), if the default formatting doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I just wanted a simple binding to a view (no editing / date picking), so a DatePicker seemed a bit to much for me. But - this is one possible solution.

Comment: @user4919196 you should be able to make the DatePicker not editable.